# Replace a part of attribute in XML using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I want to replace every occurrence of cc_2 in id with cc_0 when name in key tag ='AFI' using XSLT.
I am unable to figure out how should I traverse or scan the entire XML when 'AFI' is found.
I wanted to use replace but not able to do so.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hhs>
 <hh id="cc_2_1">
        <ad>
            <e>
                <key>PP</key>
                <value>/P</value>
            </e>
        </ad>
        <cc>cc_2</cc>
        <name>O</name>
        <recs>
            <rec id="cc_2_rec_32_18">
                <ads/>
            </rec>
            <rec id="cc_2_rec_32_185">
                <keys>
                    <key>
                        <name>AFI</name>
                    </key>
                </keys>
                <ads/>
                <keys>
                    <key>
                        <name>AFI</name>
                    </key>
                </keys>
            </rec>
    </hh>
</hhs>
```

Output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hhs>
 <hh id="cc_0_1">
        <ad>
            <e>
                <key>PP</key>
                <value>/P</value>
            </e>
        </ad>
        <cc>cc_0</cc>
        <name>O</name>
        <recs>
            <rec id="cc_0_rec_32_18">
                <ads/>
            </rec>
            <rec id="cc_0_rec_32_185">
                <keys>
                    <key>
                        <name>AFI</name>
                    </key>
                </keys>
                <ads/>
                <keys>
                    <key>
                        <name>AFI</name>
                    </key>
                </keys>
            </rec>
    </hh>
</hhs>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the attribute change I think you want something along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[.//key/name = 'AFI']//*/@id[starts-with(., 'cc_2')]">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '^cc_2', 'cc_0')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEait

If the `cc` element needs to be transformed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[.//key/name = 'AFI']//*/@id[starts-with(., 'cc_2')]">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '^cc_2', 'cc_0')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[.//key/name = 'AFI']//cc">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'cc_2', 'cc_0')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEait/1